# Php session getting mixed even with different browser session

Tags: php, session

I have a problem here. I tried to login into one account. Then opening another chrome session not another tab the previous session gets this session value and everything reset to current account value. How avoid this problem? This is how I do in my login page. MY server is Centos.

```
            $_SESSION['enterpriseID'] = $row1['enterpriseID'];
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $row1['userID'];
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $row1['userName'];
        $_SESSION['enterpriseName'] = $row1['enterpriseName'];
        $_SESSION['enterpriseID'] = $row1['enterpriseID'];
        $_SESSION['enterpriseLogo'] = $row1['enterpriseLogo'];
        $_SESSION['timeZoneOffset'] = $row1['timeZoneOffset'];
        $_SESSION['positionID'] = $row1['positionID'];
```

Sample code is as below.

```
Update tblAST Set 
astStatus='m',".
employeeIDEnd=".$_SESSION['userID'].", ".
dateTimeEnd=now() ".
Where astID=".$astID;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't use private navigation ?
Have you try with an other navigator (firefox or IE)?

Comment: But it should happened rite? Even whatever method I use right?

Comment: How do you open another session? The only way to avoid this is to use Incognito Mode.

Comment: Yes but why does session get mixed up?

Comment: Because there only is one session if you're not using incognito mode.

Comment: Ok I just tested with IE the same. I am very worried this might have integrity problem on my data.

Comment: I just test with IE the same issue

Comment: How are you creating the sesson?

Comment: @Izkata you can see in my question that is how I created the session

Comment: It looks like a known bug discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954

Comment: @TecBrat so what is the best solution to avoid mix at the db level which is very dangerous

Comment: In other words, you're not using [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Comment: @No I am using at the start of every page and infact that is the first thing after <?php

Comment: Please show us more of your code so we can tell exactly what's happening.

Comment: This question has a possible answer for you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925590/ Short expiration cookies with js to slide the expiration time forward.

Comment: @TecBrat I have update my question with sample of my query.

Answer (score 2):

The way that chrome works is that the sessions are valid through out the program, 
even if you open a new window it still has the information from all the other sessions. you can see this by using GMail, every window that you open up your inbox will load while you go to it,

as mentioned above, try using private browsing or a different browser to test the multiple sessions.

As mentioned in my comments below you need to assign a name to each session then make a multi dim array to set and retrieve the information.

$_SESSION['myapp']['username'] 
$_SESSION['myapp']['id']

Comment: The problem is that I tried on IE is the same too. I also saw some data getting session id of different customer when stored in the database that is scary

Comment: Because all browsers use a global session, and the variable gets written over. try using private mode, or even database sessions this way you can generate a key for each session, i beleive php has a way for doing that, where you reference session by keys

Comment: But why is my db also showing mixed up of the customer session value. For eg. I see the customer A having the session value of customer B being stored

Comment: i did a quick search look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions

Comment: Every page I have this session_start();

Comment: once you start the session you need to get the session from the user that is logged in. this way you can get it by key for the session that you want to write in

Comment: yes I do that by first putting session_start(); at the very top of every codes

Comment: yes you put that to start the session, that is correct but then you need to actually get the session identifier for the user, please have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: This how I get the values $_SESSION['userID'] ?

Comment: when you set the values you need to access that variable
$_SESSION['myapp']['username']
$_SESSION['myapp']['id']

Comment: @How to set then as I only know one method to set the session?

Comment: Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854105/multiple-php-sessions